# Counting the number of solutions to an inequality

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

**The problem is as follows:**

How many positive integer solutions are there to the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{10} \leq 100$?

**My solution:**

Imagine we have 100 balls (each ball representing the number one) and 10 urns. First, fill each urn with 1 ball, since we only want positive solutions.

Now we have 90 balls left and 10 urns. Let us make an 11th urn $x_{11}$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{11} = 100$.

Now we have 90 balls to be put into 11 urns, the solution is therefore $\binom{90 + 11 - 1}{90}$.

There's no answer key to this problem, so is my solution correct?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, $x_{11}$ is not required to be positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this argument is correct.  Essentially, you are making the change of variable $y_i=x_i-1$ and counting nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{10} (y_i+1) \le 100$, equivalently, $\sum_{i=1}^{10} y_i \le 100-10$.  Including the nonnegative slack variable $x_{11}$ is the simplest, but another approach is to sum up the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^{10} y_i = k$ for $k\in\{0,\dots,90\}$, yielding
$$\sum_{k=0}^{90} \binom{k+10-1}{10-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{90} \binom{k+9}{9} = \binom{90+9+1}{10} = \binom{100}{10}.$$